# WebApi Controller, POST object with child collection of complex objects

Tags: list, asp.net-mvc-4, post, asp.net-web-api

i have to POST this object structure:

```
public class Parent
{
    public List<Child> Childs {get; set;}
}

public class Child
{
    public String Name {get; set;}
}
```

I make my POST call with jquery:

```
var myjson={
   "Childs":[{"Name":"Pippo"},{"Name":"Pluto"}]
}

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/parent",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(myjson),
        traditional: true,
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert("There was an error posting the data to the server: " + error.responseText);
        }
    });
```

And this is ParentController:

```
public class ParentController : ApiController{

   [HttpPost]
   [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
   public HttpResponseMessage Post(Parent obj){
      // obj.Childs.Count is 2
      // but obj.Childs[0].Name is null
   }

}
```

The problem is i receive a parent object with two childs, but childs have null name.

---

> Update, i found a workaround
>   In this way seems to work:

```
public class ParentController : ApiController{

   [HttpPost]
   [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
   public HttpResponseMessage Post(JObject obj){
      Parent p=obj.ToObject<Parent>();
      // p.Childs[0].Name is Pippo
   }

}
```

Comment: Weird - I had the same problem, and the same workaround worked for me. Still I believe I'm doing something wrong somehow.